# SQL Get all columns where column is unique

Tags: sql

I need to select all columns from `dpgift` where `donor_id` is unique. I know how to get unique `donor_id` records from `dpgift` using:

```
SELECT distinct dpgift.donor_id from dpgift join dp on dp.donor_id = dpgift.donor_id
```

(I am joining the `dp` table to get more column fields).
Now how do I get all the columns for each unique `donor_id` by the last `gift_date`?

Expected output (there are 100+ actual columns):

```
0 => [
"donor_id" => "3838"
"gift_date" => "5/11/2018"
"amount" => "20"
"total" => "0"
"bill" => "0"
"balance" => "0"
"created_date" => "5/31/2017"
],
1 => [
"donor_id" => "3839"
"gift_date" => "12/11/2019"
"amount" => "155"
"total" => "120"
"bill" => "0"
"balance" => "0"
"created_date" => "1/8/2018"
]
```

Current output:

```
0 => [
"donor_id" => "3838"
"gift_date" => "4/6/2017"
"amount" => "5"
"total" => "0"
"bill" => "0"
"balance" => "0"
"created_date" => "5/31/2017"
],
1 => [
"donor_id" => "3838"
"gift_date" => "5/11/2018"
"amount" => "20"
"total" => "0"
"bill" => "0"
"balance" => "0"
"created_date" => "5/31/2017"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now how do I get all the columns for each unique donor_id by the last gift_date?

One method is `row_number()`:

```
select g.*
from (select g.*, dp.*,    -- select the column you want if there are duplicates
             row_number() over (partition by dp.donor_id order by g.gift_date desc) as seqnum
      from dpgift g join
           dp
           on g.donor_id = dp.donor_id
     ) g
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I get the error ```using``` isn't supported. :/

Comment: then use your on clause as before, stillit  would be strange that it doesn't work

Comment: @CourtneyErickson . . . Your question is tagged MySQL, and MySQL definitely supports `using`:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html.

Comment: I'm querying someone else's database through their API, it must not be MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Using Microsoft SQL, I found the answer to this question similar to Gordon's answer. Posting it here in case anyone else is looking for the answer.

```
Select * 
from 
(Select *, row_number() over (partition by dpgift.donor_id order by dpgift.gift_date) 
as donor from dpgift) t  
join dp on dp.donor_id = t.donor_id 
where donor = 1
```